# Ubuntu Crashes Evertime I Open System Settings

Tags: 13.10, system

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10. Every-time I open system settings Ubuntu crashes. Is there a fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center
```

This will re-install system settings.

Answer (score 0):

If this keeps happening, to a fresh install of Unity.

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:unity-team/staging
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

OR

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```