# I have installed Python 3.7.9 and made it my default one, so my Ubuntu 16.0.4 isn't stable anymore, how to solve it?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, python

I have installed **Python 3.7.9** and made it my **default**. I also changed the graphics card to **NVIDIA**, but now I **can't open the terminal**, neither using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut nor by pressing on the icon. I can still, however, open it from any folder.

Also, my **system freezes** when I open **Settings**.

When I try to add the repo for the drivers I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

Is there any solution to this mess?

I tried many solutions mentioned here and there, but none of them worked with my case so far.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Revert your Python defaults to 2.7.12 and 3.5.1, which is what your Ubuntu 16.04 system was designed to work with. You can have other versions installed...but those other versions should not be the default.

Comment: Could you share what have you tried?

Comment: Can you explain how you installed Python 3.7.9 (how you remove this will depend on how you installed it). Have you tried `sudo apt install --reinstall python python3`.

Comment: @user535733 how can I do that without re-installing the OS again? *Revert your Python defaults to 2.7.12 and 3.5.1*

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity I tried the solutions mentioned in these answers : [First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708180/python-dev-installation-error-importerror-no-module-named-apt-pkg), [Second](https://askubuntu.com/questions/480908/problem-with-update-manager-no-module-named-apt-pkg-in-ubuntu-13-10-having-i), [Third](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397521/ubuntu-crashes-evertime-i-open-system-settings), and also `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/control-center/`.

Comment: How you fix the problem depends upon how you created the problem. Your question does not include the steps you followed to install Py3.7.9 and the steps you followed to make it the default version of Python3.

Comment: @Kurankat I did, but it didn't work with me.